# send tweet from c# asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter, oauth, tweetsharp

I have an ASP.net (c#) website which I'd like to send a tweet from (when an event occurs so not a front facing feature).

I've looked at the DLL libraries, but cannot find how to use this with just websites - not an application.

Is there any way to simply connect and send a tweet? It seems everything I come up with uses this DLL method for a wrapper...

thanks for any info!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what your looking for ?

http://www.twitterizer.net/

Comment: this does look good, but the documentation says "Get Started Using Twitterizer -- 1. Add the Twitterizer2.dll file as a reference in your application." - I'm not sure where to add this DLL in my web site...?

Comment: Add it as a reference do you need help doing that ? Looks like its on NuGet I can help you install that if you want

Answer (score 0):

With Twitter API 1.1 you would wanna use Tweetsharp instead

https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp